# YouTube downloader application with PySimpleGUI in Python

Tags: python, youtube

I would appreciate a review of my Python script that interacts with the YouTube API and downloads videos or audio from YouTube URLs or playlists. The script uses the pytube library for downloading and PySimpleGUI for the GUI.

Here is the script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import threading
import urllib.error

import pytube.exceptions
import data
import webbrowser
import PySimpleGUI as psg
from datetime import datetime
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube.exceptions import VideoUnavailable


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """PyInstaller requirement,
    Get an absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller."""
    base_path = getattr(sys, "_MEIPASS", os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


version = "1.1"
themes = ["LightGrey", "DarkGrey4"]
colors = ["#FBFBFB", "#52524E"]
yt_playlist = []
table_list = []
download_start_time = datetime.now()


def settings_popup():
    """Creates a new window with app information / settings."""
    layout = [[psg.Image(filename=resource_path("./images/youtube.png"))],
              [psg.Text(f"YOUTUBE GETTER v{version}\nby Paichiwo\n2023\n\n{data.popup_message}",
                        justification='c')],
              [psg.Image(filename=resource_path("./images/github.png")),
               psg.Text("GitHub",
                        font=("Arial", 10, "underline"),
                        enable_events=True)],
              [psg.Text("")],
              [psg.Button('OK')]]
    window = psg.Window("Information",
                        layout,
                        element_justification='c',
                        grab_anywhere=True,
                        finalize=True,
                        icon=resource_path("./images/youtube.png"))
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event in "GitHub":
            webbrowser.open(data.github_link)
        window.close()


def count_file_size(size_bytes):
    """Count the stream file sizes."""
    return round(size_bytes / (1024 * 1024), 1)


def get_playlist_links(url):
    """Create a list with user links."""
    if "playlist" in url:
        p = Playlist(url)
        for link in p.video_urls:
            yt_playlist.append(link)
    else:
        yt_playlist.append(url)


def update_table(i_tag, output_format,  window):
    """Update the table with user links information."""
    table_list.clear()
    for url in yt_playlist:
        yt = YouTube(url)
        try:
            table_list.append(
                [yt.streams.get_by_itag(i_tag).title,
                 output_format,
                 f"{count_file_size(yt.streams.get_by_itag(i_tag).filesize)} MB",
                 "0%",
                 "0 Mb/s",
                 "Queued"])
        except AttributeError:
            table_list.append(
                [yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().title,
                 output_format,
                 f"{count_file_size(yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().filesize)} MB",
                 "0%",
                 "0 Mb/s",
                 "Queued"])
    window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)


def download_video(playlist, output_path, window):
    """Download video stream - highest resolution."""
    for index, link in enumerate(playlist):
        yt = YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=lambda stream, chunk, bytes_remaining: count_progress(index, stream,
                                                                                                      chunk,
                                                                                                      bytes_remaining,
                                                                                                      window))
        yt_stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        # Set status to 'downloading'
        table_list[index][5] = "Downloading"
        window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)
        try:
            yt_stream.download(output_path=output_path, filename=yt_stream.default_filename)
            # Set status to 'complete'
            table_list[index][5] = "Complete"
            window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)
        except (PermissionError, RuntimeError):
            psg.popup("ERROR: Permission Error.")


def download_audio(playlist, output_path, window):
    """Download audio stream."""
    for index, link in enumerate(playlist):
        yt = YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=lambda stream, chunk, bytes_remaining: count_progress(index, stream,
                                                                                                      chunk,
                                                                                                      bytes_remaining,
                                                                                                      window))
        yt_stream = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
        # Set status to 'downloading'
        table_list[index][5] = "Downloading"
        window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)

        # change an extension to mp3 if mp4 audio downloaded.
        if yt_stream.mime_type == "audio/mp4":
            filename = yt_stream.default_filename.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + ".mp3"
        else:
            filename = yt_stream.default_filename
        try:
            yt_stream.download(output_path=output_path, filename=filename)
            # Set status to 'complete'
            table_list[index][5] = "Complete"
            window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)
        except (PermissionError, RuntimeError):
            psg.popup("ERROR: Permission Error.")


def count_progress(index, stream, chunk, bytes_remaining, window):
    """Count the progress of downloading file."""
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    percentage_completion = round(bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100, 2)
    table_list[index][3] = f"{percentage_completion}%"

    # Calculate and update the download speed
    elapsed_time = (datetime.now() - download_start_time).total_seconds()
    download_speed = bytes_downloaded / (1024 * elapsed_time)  # Convert bytes/sec to kilobytes/sec
    table_list[index][4] = f"{round(download_speed, 2)} KB/s"

    window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)


def create_window(theme):
    """Application layout for PySimpleGUI."""
    psg.theme(theme)

    layout = [

        [psg.Text("Enter URLs:"),
         psg.Push(),
         psg.Text("Ext:"),
         psg.Combo(values=["mp4", "mp3"],
                   default_value="mp3",
                   background_color="light grey",
                   text_color="black",
                   pad=5,
                   k="-FORMAT-"),
         psg.Button(image_filename=resource_path("./images/icons_black/sun.png"),
                    button_color=colors[0],
                    border_width=0,
                    pad=5,
                    k="-THEME-"),
         psg.Button(image_filename=resource_path("./images/icons_black/setting.png"),
                    button_color=colors[0],
                    border_width=0,
                    pad=5,
                    k="-SETTINGS-")],

        [psg.Input(focus=True,
                   background_color="light grey",
                   text_color="black",
                   expand_x=True,
                   border_width=0,
                   pad=5,
                   right_click_menu=["%Right", ["Paste"]],
                   k="-URL-"),
         psg.Button('Submit', visible=False, bind_return_key=True),
         psg.Button("Add",
                    border_width=0,
                    size=8,
                    pad=5,
                    k="-ADD-")],

        [psg.Image(filename=resource_path("./images/icons_black/folder.png")),
         psg.Input("C:/Users/",
                   background_color="light grey",
                   text_color="black",
                   expand_x=True,
                   border_width=0,
                   k="-DOWNLOAD-FOLDER-"),
         psg.FolderBrowse("Browse",
                          initial_folder="C:/Users/lzeru/Desktop/",
                          size=(8, 1),
                          k="-DOTS-")],

        [psg.Table(values=[],
                   headings=["Title", "Ext", "Size", "Progress", "Speed", "Status"],
                   col_widths=[33, 7, 8, 6, 8, 12],
                   auto_size_columns=False,
                   justification="c",
                   background_color="light grey",
                   alternating_row_color="grey",
                   text_color="black",
                   size=(10, 20),
                   expand_x=True,
                   border_width=0,
                   pad=5,
                   k="-TABLE-")],

        [psg.Button("Clear",
                    border_width=0,
                    size=8,
                    pad=5,
                    k="-CLEAR-"),
         psg.Push(),
         psg.Button("Download",
                    border_width=0,
                    size=8,
                    pad=5,
                    k="-DOWNLOAD-")]
    ]
    return psg.Window(f"YouTube Getter v{version}",
                      layout=layout,
                      size=(800, 500),
                      element_justification="c",
                      resizable=True,
                      icon=resource_path("./images/youtube.png"),
                      finalize=True)


def main():
    """Main function for the YouTube Getter application."""
    window = create_window(themes[0])
    themes_counter = 1
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        elif event == "Paste":
            window["-URL-"].update(psg.clipboard_get())

        elif event == "-THEME-":
            theme = themes[themes_counter % len(themes)]
            color = colors[themes_counter % len(themes)]
            window.close()
            window = create_window(theme)
            window["-SETTINGS-"].update(button_color=color)
            window["-THEME-"].update(button_color=color)
            themes_counter += 1

        elif event == "-SETTINGS-":
            settings_popup()

        elif event == "-ADD-" or event == "Submit":
            if values["-URL-"]:
                try:
                    get_playlist_links(values["-URL-"])
                    if values["-FORMAT-"] == "mp4":
                        update_table(22, "mp4", window)
                    else:
                        update_table(140, "mp3", window)

                except VideoUnavailable:
                    psg.popup("ERROR: Video is age restricted.")
                except pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError:
                    psg.popup("ERROR: Wrong URL.")
                except (urllib.error.URLError, urllib.error.HTTPError):
                    psg.popup("ERROR: Internal error.")
            else:
                psg.Popup("ERROR: No url detected.")

        elif event == "-CLEAR-":
            yt_playlist.clear()
            table_list.clear()
            window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)

        elif event == "-DOWNLOAD-":
            output_format = values["-FORMAT-"]
            output_path = values["-DOWNLOAD-FOLDER-"]
            if output_format == "mp4":
                threading.Thread(target=download_video, args=(yt_playlist.copy(), output_path, window)).start()
                print(type(window["-TABLE-"]))
            else:
                threading.Thread(target=download_audio, args=(yt_playlist.copy(), output_path, window)).start()

    window.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can find the complete script on [GitHub](https://github.com/paichiwo/youtube-getter/).

Specifically, I would like feedback on the following aspects:

- Code organization: Are the functions appropriately placed and structured?
- Error handling: Am I handling exceptions properly? Are there any potential error scenarios I'm not considering?
- Efficiency: Is there a more efficient way to perform the video and audio downloads?
- GUI design: Is the GUI layout clear and user-friendly? Any suggestions for improvement?
- Code readability: Is my code easy to read and understand? Are there any areas where I can improve readability?

Any other suggestions or feedback are also welcome. If you feeling like writing PR with improvements or opening an Issue, please do.

Answer (score 4):

I've recently reviewed another question with a very similar goal to yours. You even use the same GUI library: [YouTube to MP3 - Uses PySimpleGUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/280201/52915).

I'd recommend you, the other author and any other interested reader to read the code on both questions and draw your/their own conclusions about the pros and cons of either/both.

---

> Am I handling exceptions properly? Are there any potential error scenarios I'm not considering?

I do like that you're catching your errors separately. It's very easy to go the catch-all route and run into problems later. You didn't. If you want to be complete and specifically interested in potential error scenarios you missed, you're using threads. Yet you're not catching anything about threading gone wrong. What if you can no longer spawn new ones? There's [`ThreadError`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537542/1014587) to consider (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1834919/1014587)), although it's rare to run into and a pain to test for. Usually keeping count of the threads in use and figuring out a practical ceiling is sufficient. Currently you're doing neither.

Checking for `PermissionError` and `RuntimeError` in the `download_video` and `download_audio` functions leads to duplication. After a closer look, it appears that's not the only similarity those functions have. Consider extracting the duplication into a new function. After all, the only difference is:

```
yt_stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
```

vs

```
yt_stream = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
```

1 line difference and they write the same variable! Something so minor that the obvious solution would be making them one function with video/audio as extra argument and something as simple as a ternary would suffice in getting the job done. Code duplication is a great way of trying things out with minor differences. Once you've found it works, get rid of the duplication.

As for readability, you've split up most of your code into functions. That helps a lot. Your `main` function is still pretty long though. 57 lines, 49 if we exclude the ones for vertical whitespace. We can easily (more than) half that number, down to 23:

```
def main():
    """Main function for the YouTube Getter application."""
    window = create_window(themes[0])
    themes_counter = 1
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "Paste":
            window["-URL-"].update(psg.clipboard_get())
        elif event == "-THEME-":
            # Put this in a function
        elif event == "-SETTINGS-":
            settings_popup()
        elif event == "-ADD-" or event == "Submit":
            # Put this in a function
        elif event == "-CLEAR-":
            yt_playlist.clear()
            table_list.clear()
            window["-TABLE-"].update(table_list)
        elif event == "-DOWNLOAD-":
            # Put this in a function
    window.close()
```

When you go that route, every `event` should eventually get their own function. Perhaps you can eventually map them or find that [structural pattern matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) can be helpful.

Honestly, the clean approach would eventually go a step beyond:

```
def main():
    """Main function for the YouTube Getter application."""
    window = create_window(themes[0])
    themes_counter = 1
    while True:
        # Put this in a function
    window.close()
```

That's it. The [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) applies to modules and functions. When in doubt, a function should do one thing and one thing only. Functions in functions in functions can lead to very readable code when done correctly. Every event should definitely have its own function. If anything, I'd start there.